# Kill a process after a time limit is reached, or let it run till completion, whichever is faster

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, php

The following posts teach us how to run a process for some time:
[What is a simple way to let a command run for 5 minutes?](https://superuser.com/questions/1045239/what-is-a-simple-way-to-let-a-command-run-for-5-minutes)
[Kill process after it's been allowed to run for some time](https://superuser.com/questions/153735/kill-process-after-its-been-allowed-to-run-for-some-time)

I particularly like this answer:

```
YourCommand & read -t 300 ;  kill $!                           # 1st version
```

from
https://superuser.com/a/1045496

However, what if I like the whole command to terminate completely if the process takes lesser time than the original specified time limit to finish?

I ask this because I am actually running this command in a subshell created by a PHP script:

```
// $wtime is some time limit
$cmd = "MyCommand & read -t {$wtime}; kill $!";
shell_exec($cmd);
```

My PHP script will not continue to the next line after shell_exec($cmd) if "read -t..." does not finish, if MyCommand finishes faster than it.

NOTE: I do not need an answer that makes use of PHP, but just the shell. That's why I am posting it here and not on Stack Overflow. However, I do welcome any answer that makes use of PHP as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility that deals with this for you - [`timeout`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html).

For example:

```
timeout 5s sleep 30
```

- `-s INT` - By default, SIGTERM is sent, but you can change this, e.g: for SIGINT
- `-k ${DURATION}` - If your application *should* handle the signal, but may get stuck, you can also give this argument to send a SIGKILL some time after the original signal was sent.
- `--preserve-status` - If the application should handle the signal and then return a useful exit code, then you can also give this argument, otherwise `timeout` will return 124 if the timeout expires.